# show two divs when tick the checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two divs with same class when i tick the checkbox these two divs should be open but only one div is opening. tried below script (in snippet) to open divs. Anything wrong? please help me.

```js
function ShowHideDiv() {
  var chkYes = document.getElementById("chkYes");
  var pro = document.getElementsByClassName("pro")[0];
  pro.style.display = chkYes.checked ? "block" : "none";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkYes" name="chkPassPort" onclick="ShowHideDiv()">Is Pro Contact</div>
<div class="pro" style="display: none">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="userfile">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="description" rows="3" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="services" placeholder="Services"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pro" style="display:none;">
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="सविस्तर माहिती"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="सुविधा"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're using **`document.getElementsByClassName("pro")[0]`** thus getting only the first element having that class.

Comment: yes thanks...got it as i want..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove `[0]` from

```
var pro = document.getElementsByClassName("pro")[0];
```

and add for loop as `[0]` will affect only first element from `NodeList`

```js
function ShowHideDiv() {
  var chkYes = document.getElementById("chkYes");
  var pro = document.getElementsByClassName("pro");
  for (var i = pro.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
 pro[i].style.display = chkYes.checked ? "block" : "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkYes" name="chkPassPort" onclick="ShowHideDiv()">Is Pro Contact</div>
<div class="pro" style="display: none">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="userfile">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="description" rows="3" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="services" placeholder="Services"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pro" style="display:none;">
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="सविस्तर माहिती"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="सुविधा"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

```
function ShowHideDiv() {
  var chkYes = document.getElementById("chkYes");
  for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("pro").length; i++){
      var pro = document.getElementsByClassName("pro")[i];
      pro.style.display = chkYes.checked ? "block" : "none";
  }
}
```